# Handling huge Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Need your help badly. I am dealing with a workbook which has 7000 rows X 5000 columns data in one sheet. Each of this datapoint has to be manipulated  and pasted in another sheet. The manipulations is relatively simple where each manipulation will take less than 10 lines of code (simple multiplications and divisions with a couple of Ifs). However, the file crashes every now and then and getting various types of errors. The problem is the filesize. To overcome this problem, I am trying a few approaches

a) Separate the data and output in different files. Keep both files open and take data chunk by chunk (typically 200 rows x 5000 columns) and manipulate that and paste that in output file. However, if both files are open, then I am not sure it remedies the problem since the memory consumed will be same either way i.e. instead of one file consuming a large memory, it would be two files together consuming the same memory.

b) Separate the data and output in different files. Access the data in the data file while it is still closed by inserting links in the output file through a macro, manipulate the data and paste it in output. This can be done chunk by chunk.

c) Separate the data and output in different files. Run a macro to open the data file and load a chunk of data say 200 rows into memory into an array and close it. Process the array and open the output file and paste the array results.

Which of the three approaches are better? I am sure there are other methods which are more efficient. Kindly suggest.

I am not familiar with Access but I tried to import the raw data into Access and it failed because it allowed only 255 columns.

Is there a way to keep the file open but wash it in and out of Memory. Then slight variations to a and c above can be tried. (I am afraid repeated opening and closing will crash the file.)

Look forward to your suggestions

Comment: I am not sure that your Excel sheet is huge by today's standards, on e.g. a machine with 8Gbytes of RAM. Did you try some alternative spreadsheet like the just released [LibreOffice 4.2](http://www.libreoffice.org/)

Comment: Thanks Basile. I dont know much about LibreOffice. I broke data into 5 files and the files together are over 600MB. There is some duplication and even after removing duplication, I expect the file to be about 3-400 MB if I put the data in the same file. Do you have a suggestion? My Machine is 6GB. Do you still think this can be done in Excel without any hitch and no such "fancy" algorithms stated above are necessary? Do you think I would have to upgrade to 8GB RAM? Kindly let me know.

Comment: I have no idea about Excel. I never used it, and I never used any Microsoft Windows system (I'm using Linux since 1994). I think you should try the just released Libreoffice 4.2 (it is free software, and also runs on Windows)

Comment: Look forward to more responses. Please help

Comment: For those who were following this thread. I realized 'a' did not save any memory. 'c' would have taken a long time anyway for opening and closing the file. 'b' seemed promising but i ran into an issue implementing Indirect function to access a value from a closed workbook. As an alternative, I had to construct a link for each of the cells by changing the counters for the cell row and cell column to access the values in the closed workbook. This meant that the program was overall pretty slow. Thanks anyway. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046546/using-indirect-function-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to leave Excel, one trick you can use is to save the base excel file as a binary ".xlsb". This will clean out a lot of potential rubbish that might be in the file (it all depends on where it first came from.)

I just shrank a load of webdata by 99.5% - from 300MB to 1.5MB - by doing this, and now the various manipulation in excel works like a dream.

The other trick (from the 80s :) ) if you are using a lot of in cell formulae rather than a macro to iterate through, is to:

1. turn calculate off.
2. copy your formulae
3. turn calculate on, or just run calculate manually
4. copy and paste-special-values the formulae outputs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using a scripting language of your choice and working with decomposition/composition of spreadsheets in it.

I was composing and decomposing spreadsheets back in the days (in PHP, oh shame) and it worked like a charm. I wasn't even using any libraries.

Just grab yourself [xlutils](https://github.com/python-excel/xlutils) library for Python and get your hands dirty.

Comment: Thanks DMunchkin. Don't have any skills other than VBA :-(.