# using indirect function in Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am using indirect function to create a link into another closed workbook. The objective is to retrieve the values without opening the workbook. I have used the following in one place which works.

```
=INDIRECT("[NVOL.xlsb]Sheet1!A"&C6)
```

However, in another place in the same sheet, the following does not work (gives a #ref error)

```
=INDIRECT("[MTM.xlsb]Sorted!A"&B6)
```

It appears `[NVOL.xlsb]` is taken as a substitute for the full path but the full path is not visible. I have two questions

a) The path in the former case (NVOL) somehow vanished. How do I make it sure it is visible so that the path can be changed if necessary?

b) How to make sure the MTM.xlsb is infact backed by a full path?

Comment: `I am using indirect function to create a link into another closed workbook` - you can't use idirect for closed workbook

Comment: Thanks simoco. You are spot on!!! I opened the workbook and the link which wasnt working worked. And the opposite for the other workbook (which incidentally did not work after the workbook was closed)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20346996/641067

Comment: Thanks brettdj for having a look and finding this out. I am doing the same thing as suggested in the thread posted by you. This was always my backup plan and I fell back on this as the Indirect method did not work. By the way, if you have time, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508014/handling-huge-excel-file   I am trying to do (b) in the above thread. Do you have a view on what is being attempted? I guess it may make the file more stable but not sure it may make it faster. Apologize in advance for going off topic

Comment: I implemented links without using the indirect function as per the link suggested by brettdj. There was no benefit from a speed point of view but I guess the macro and the file became stable. Thanks to all those who have contributed and viewed this thread. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both** workbooks must be open and Excel is very fussy about the syntax:

=INDIRECT("'C:\TestFolder[ABC.xls]NewName'!B" & A1)

(double quote) (single quote) (path name) (bracket) (file name) (close bracket) (!) (cell address) (double quote)

Comment: Thanks. The whole idea was to retrieve a value from a closed workbook. Indirect obviously does not help.