# Reference a file that changes daily / Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Before I jump into a VBA solution, I wanted to know if it was possible to update a filename of a closed workbook I am referencing.

The formula reads,

`=SUMIF('L:path\[filename - "&TEXT(WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1),"yyyymmdd")&".xlsx]Sheet'!$BF:$BF,"criteria",'L:path\[filename - "&TEXT(WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1),"yyyymmdd")&".xlsx]Sheet'!$DX:$DX)`

To clarify, the path the filename would look something like this, `This is the filename - yyyymmdd.xlsb`

Someone at work said it's not possible to change the filename because it's a string.  If that is the case could someone just expand on that a bit?

Comment: Do you mean update the file's name upon closing the document based upon the logic in the above formulas?

Comment: Yes.  In general, can the file name change with the date whether it's upon closing the workbook or refreshing the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really. If you have "Book1.xls" and "Book2.xls", what you can do it put this formula in book1:

=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]", CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)

This will return the name (only) of Book1. You could then reference that cell from Book2. HOwever, if you change Book1's name to something else, the reference will be broken and you will have to manually change the reference (pick the file from the update link manager). It seems excel uses absolute paths, including filename, to reference other workbook. You would need to have a way to store a flexible reference to that workbook into Book2. But the only way to do is VBA.

Interestingly however you can do that:

- Create a reference in book2 pointing to a cell in book1. You get the value of that cell in book2.
- Close everything.
- Open only book1, edit the referenced cell. Close & save book1.
- Book2, when you open it, will ask you if you want to update the link, and you can see the updated value even if book1 is still closed.

The other idea that I had was to use INDIRECT, like what is done there: [using indirect function in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046546/using-indirect-function-in-excel)

But it won't work for closed workbook and that's one of your requirements.

So VBA it is.

Comment: I clicked yours as the correct answer because it clarified that I can't do it without VBA.  I have limited accessibility (basically only read rights) to most files at the moment so I won't be able to experiment with the above.  Thanks.